# What is the best way to clear the Validation Label in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am doing a basic validation for user input form, where I attached nameOfValidationLabel under each input. But these labels won't clear after the user correct the problem by adding the required text, so I added nameOfLable.setText(null) for each one of them at the beginning of the script. ok, that did the trick, but what happens if I have 20 or more validation labels.... is this the right way of doing it? Also, any clue on how to validate radio button section?

```
@FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    userIdLabel.setText(null);
    passwordLabel.setText(null);
    ipValueLabel.setText(null);


    Stage stage;
    Parent root;
    if(event.getSource()==btn1){

        if ((ipValue.getText().isEmpty() || ipValue.getText() == null)) {
         ipValueLabel.setText("*IP address is required");
        }
        else if ((userId.getText().isEmpty() || userId.getText() == null)) {
         userIdLabel.setText("*Enter Your UserID");
        }

        else if ((password.getText().isEmpty() || password.getText() == null)) {
         passwordLabel.setText("*Enter Your Password");
        }

        else {
       stage=new Stage();
       root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Myfile.fxml"));
       stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
       stage.setTitle("Status Page");
       stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
       stage.initOwner(btn1.getScene().getWindow());
       stage.showAndWait();}

    }
    else {
        stage=(Stage) btn2.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();

    }


}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

}

Comment: Have you already checked this tutorial? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/text-field.htm#BABBCEIG

Comment: Yes, I believe the clear button will clear the entire form, but I only want to clear the labels

Comment: There are many Frameworks ready to use: [FXForm2](http://dooapp.github.io/FXForm2/) for doing form generation too, or [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#decorationvalidation) for having other goods things and last but not least [JideFX](http://www.jidesoft.com/jidefx/JideFX_Validation_Developer_Guide.pdf)